# Django check files and add to DB

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I would like to ask, what could be the best approach to realize something like: I will insert a `pdf` file to `static folder` in Django. After That I want Django to check if there is a new file in `static folder` and if is add `file name` to Django's sqlite. 
Whole process I'm trying to do: I have a `calendar app` in my Django site. I want to check a new `pdf file` in static folder and save it to that `calendar app` DB, so it will be as a `pdf link` in certain day in `calendar app`

Comment: is it manually copy and paste or through some function(API)?

Comment: @Kushan Gunasekera manually... I get that `pdf files` from email